# Inject javascript file

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've extended SwaggerUI using my custom index.html and plugin as described in the doc. However I want to keep my index.html as near to the default as possible. That's why I want to extract my plugin into a separate file. The doc says that InjectOnCompleteJavaScript is not supported in the new versions. The question is how to inject custom javascript files?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="your_js_file.js"></script>` should do it.

Comment: The thing is how to include the file on server side

Comment: do you have a link to that `The doc says that InjectOnCompleteJavaScript is not supported` ...... I still see it on the readme: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#customizations-via-the-configuration-api

Comment: You linked the old repo, they moved to .NET Core. `The InjectOnCompleteJavaScript and InjectOnFailureJavaScript options have been removed because the latest version of swagger-ui doesn't expose the neccessary hooks. Instead, it provides a flexible customization system based on concepts and patterns from React and Redux. To leverage this, you'll need to provide a custom version of index.html as described below.` - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#apply-swagger-ui-parameters